# Unable to mock utility function using import.meta to read file in Jest test

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I am reading a a file using import.meta to resolve the directory which fails when trying to mock it in a function. Here is the part of the code which I want to mock

```js
                  // readFileUtil
                  const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
                  const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
                  
                  export async function readFile(fileName: string){
                      try {
                       const data = await fs.promises.readFile(fileName, 'utf8')
                       return data
                      } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                      }
                   }
```

I am then using the code above to read a file like this in some code:

```js
                import readFileUtils from '../file-utils'
                import  dataProcessor from '../data/processor 
                
                function processData(fileName:string){
                   const data = await fs.promises.readFile(fileName, 'utf8')
                   //rest of code uses data
                }
```

I then wrote a Jest test which tests the processData function like this

```js
                import readFileUtils from '../file-utils'
                import  dataProcessor from '../data/processor 
                
                jest.mock('../file-utils)' 
                describe('Data Processing suite' () => {
                    const fileName = 'resources/data.xml
                    processData(fileName) 
                }
```

Unfortunately I get the following error

**The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022'...etc**

I have no idea how to solve this issue. I did a lot of online searches but everything I tried does not work. I did the following:

```js
              {
              "compilerOptions": {
                 "target": "esnext",
                 "module": "esnext",
               ...
```

I also installed  '**npm install ts-jest-mock-import-meta**' but none of these solutions worked

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get solve the import.meta error issue. By doing the following.

First, I installed the following

```
npm install @babel/preset-typescript --save-dev
```

Next, I added created a file, babel.config.js and added the following code;

```js
          module.exports = {
             presets: [
                ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
                 "@babel/preset-typescript",
              ],
         };
```

I am still unable to get the mocking of the file reading function to work.

Comment: Incredible, actually worked

Comment: I did not update this comment. I actually got it to work a while ago. Thank you for your response.